# FPDF exports .html instead of .pdf, only on Mac

Tags: php, macos, pdf, export, fpdf

I'm using the PHP library FPDF to generate PDFs on my website.
It works GREAT on all devices EXCEPT Mac. It saves a .html file instead of .pdf.
Even iPhones work perfectly.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
        
require('includes/fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {}
$mypdf = new FPDF();

// Content of PDF begins
// [...]
// Content of PDF ends

$file = utf8_decode('test.pdf');
$mypdf->Output('F', 'includes/exports/'.$file);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file) ."\""); 
readfile('includes/exports/'.$file);
exit(); ?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which browser are you using on your Mac computer?

Comment: The browser I'm using is Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve it is by storing the PDF and showing a download link to the user. Good workaround